# ¿Cómo puedo emitir un mensaje en jsonresult en mvc 5 a la hora de guardar o si ocurrió un error?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Deseo emitir un mensaje si se elimina correctamente en label o otra forma de hacerlo si ocurre dicho error... utilizo un modal para eliminar pero deseo enviar un mensaje al usuario para confirmar si se eliminó...

**Controller en mvc 5**

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult Eliminar(int id = 0)
{
    try
    {
        Empleado empleado = empleados.Where(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
        empleados.Remove(empleado);
        return Json(empleados, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        return Json(false);
    }
}
```

```
@section Scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $('.eliminar').click(function () {
                var idEliminar = $(this).attr("data-id");
                $("#btnEliminar").attr("data-eliminar", idEliminar);
                $("#myModal").modal();
            });
            $("#btnEliminar").click(function () {
                var idEliminar = $(this).attr("data-eliminar");
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Empleado/Eliminar',
                    type: 'get',
                    data: { id: idEliminar },
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (result) {
                        console.log("Exito");
                        $("#" + idEliminar).remove();
                        $("#myModal").modal('hide');
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        console.log("fallo");
                    }
                });
            });
    </script>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Primero crea una clase basica, yo uso esta.

```
public class Result
{
    public string _result, _message, _URL;
    public object _body;
    public int? _cant;
}
```

Luego, tu metodo haslo asi.

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult Eliminar(int id = 0)
{
    Result datos = null;
    try
    {
        Empleado empleado = empleados.Where(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
        empleados.Remove(empleado);
        datos.message = "success";
        datos.result_ = "success";
        datos.cant = 1;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        datos.message = ex.Message;
        datos.result_ = "error";
    }
    return Json(datos);
}
```

Para llamarlo usa asi el ajax.

```
@section Scripts{
<script type="text/javascript">
        $('.eliminar').click(function () {
            var idEliminar = $(this).attr("data-id");
            $("#btnEliminar").attr("data-eliminar", idEliminar);
            $("#myModal").modal();
        });
        $("#btnEliminar").click(function () {
            var idEliminar = $(this).attr("data-eliminar");
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Empleado/Eliminar',
                type: 'get',
                data: { id: idEliminar },
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                success: function (result) {
                    if(result.result_ == 'success'){
                         console.log("Exito");
                         $("#" + idEliminar).remove();
                         $("#myModal").modal('hide');
                    }else{
                        console.log("error", result.message);
                    }
                },
                error: function (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }
            });
        });
</script>
}
```

Comment: No me funciona el código lo que deseo es un mensaje de confirmación a la hora de eliminar...en jsonresult

Comment: @EduardoEnriqueMorenoCaldero segun tu pregunta entiendo que cuando ocurra algún error en el controlador, se muestre un mensaje del lado del cliente como una ventana pop o un mensaje emergente verdad?

Comment: No necesariamente un ventana modal por que utilizo un modal a la hora de eliminar como confirmación si desea eliminar

Comment: Ya mira, siempre hay una ejecucion de servidor, ya sea en caso satisfactorio o si ocurrio un error, el problema es como parametrizarlo, para eso esta esa clase base, `Result` con esa clase, su asignas parametros si termino de forma satisfactoria o con error en el parametro `_result` si deseas retornar un mensaje (en tu caso el `message` del catch) se lo asignas a la variable message, y si quieres devolver objetos o una coleccion de objetos, se lo asignas al body, ya que es un objeto del tipo `object` y puedes asignarle lo que sea, si deseas realizar despues una redireccion se lo asignas a URL.

Comment: pero como emito ese mensaje de error

Comment: @EduardoEnriqueMorenoCaldero esta en el código. `console.log("error", result.message);`

Comment: No me funciona y mas bien manda error y se quiebra el programa

Answer (score 1):

Mi sugerencia es que te vayas adaptando a trabajar estos casos como una [**API**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interfaz_de_programaci%C3%B3n_de_aplicaciones), verás que es bastante más *expresivo* hacerlo así.

El protocolo **HTTP/HTTPS** funciona con peticiones de solicitudes (`Request`) y respuestas (`Response`). Además del contenido, en estas peticiones viajan cabeceras entre las que se encuentra una de [código de estatus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes). ¿Has visto alguna vez una de esas páginas de "error 404"? Ese número es el código que viajó en la cabecera.

Este código puede ser manipulado en el servidor:

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult Eliminar(int id = 0)
{
    try
    {
        Empleado empleado = empleados.Where(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
        empleados.Remove(empleado);
        return Json(empleados, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Aquí empieza
        Response.StatusCode = 500; // Error de servidor
        Response.StatusDescription = ex.Message;
        return null;
        /*
         * La razón para hacer un return null es que el método
         * necesita emitir un resultado o lanzar una excepción;
         * retornar null es menos costoso.
         */
    }
}
```

De esta manera, en el lado del cliente es muy fácil capturar ese error:

```
$("#btnEliminar").click(function () {
    var idEliminar = $(this).attr("data-eliminar");
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Empleado/Eliminar',
        type: 'get',
        data: { id: idEliminar },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (result) {
            console.log("Exito");
            $("#" + idEliminar).remove();
            $("#myModal").modal('hide');
        },
// AQUÍ ABAJO OCURRE LA MAGIA:
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(error);
            // $("#Alerta").html(error.statusText);
            // Demás control que requieras.
        }
    });
});
```

---

(Editado)

#### Para realizar modificaciones, no uses «Get»

***(Recomendación)*** Existen distintos *verbos* de acción en el protocolo HTTP, lo ideal para hacer una eliminación sería usar el verbo *delete* (`[HttpDelete]` en lugar de `[HttpGet]` como atributo del método), pero ya que no estamos hablando de una API en realidad, lo mejor sería por lo menos hacerlo con *post* (`[HttpPost]`). No necesitas un `get` para obtener datos.